# counter in crystal report formula's that is added according to if condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

The problem is that i want to make a counter that is incremented by one on conditional statement in a formula. what is happening is that the counter is reset at the next conditional statement.
the report is about grades transcript and i want to count the courses that the student failed.

```
numbervar icount;
if isnumeric({student_grade_temp1.FG500_num}) then(
if tonumber({student_grade_temp1.FG500_num})<50 then
icount:=icount+1;)
else if   ({student_grade_temp1.FG500_num})="-"then
icount:=icount+1;


if isnumeric({student_grade_temp1.FG501_num}) then(
if tonumber({student_grade_temp1.FG501_num})<50 then
icount:=icount+1;)
else if   ({student_grade_temp1.FG501_num})="-"then
icount:=icount+1
```

in this example i am working on two courses 500 and 501 each one is an independent field from the other."-" reveals that the student didn't make the exam.
in the case (a student) i am working with the course 500 the student failed in  course and 501 the student passes, so count should give one, but it is giving me 0.

Comment: In which section are you resetting the counter variable?

Comment: Change `numbervar icount;` to `Shared numbervar icount;`

Comment: @Furtiro...that should be an issue becuase by default it has global scope which will work in a single report unless there is sub report